# Truncating milliseconds out of DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

When I use `pandas.date_range()`, I sometimes have timestamp that have lots of milliseconds that I don't wish to keep.

Suppose I do...

```
import pandas as pd
dr = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-01-03', periods=15)
>>> dr
DatetimeIndex([          '2011-01-01 00:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 03:25:42.857142784',
               '2011-01-01 06:51:25.714285824',
               '2011-01-01 10:17:08.571428608',
               '2011-01-01 13:42:51.428571392',
               '2011-01-01 17:08:34.285714176',
               '2011-01-01 20:34:17.142857216',
                         '2011-01-02 00:00:00',
               '2011-01-02 03:25:42.857142784',
               '2011-01-02 06:51:25.714285824',
               '2011-01-02 10:17:08.571428608',
               '2011-01-02 13:42:51.428571392',
               '2011-01-02 17:08:34.285714176',
               '2011-01-02 20:34:17.142857216',
                         '2011-01-03 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

To ignore the currend miliseconds, I am forced to do this.

```
>>> t = []
>>> for item in dr:
...  idx = str(item).find('.')
...  if idx != -1:
...   item = str(item)[:idx]
...  t.append(pd.to_datetime(item))
...
>>> t
[Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-01 03:25:42'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-01 06:51:25'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-01 10:17:08'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-01 13:42:51'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-01 17:08:34'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-01 20:34:17'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-02 00:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-02 03:25:42'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-02 06:51:25'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-02 10:17:08'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-02 13:42:51'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-02 17:08:34'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-02 20:34:17'), 
 Timestamp('2011-01-03 00:00:00')]
```

Is there a better way ?
I already tried this...

1. `dr = [ pd.to_datetime(item, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for item in dr ]`

But it doesn't do anything.

2. `(pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-01-03', periods=15)).astype('datetime64[s]')`

But it says it can't cast it.

3. `dr = (dr.to_series()).apply(lambda x:x.replace(microseconds=0))`

But this line doesn't solve my problem, as...

```
2018-04-17 15:07:04.777777664 gives --> 2018-04-17 15:07:04.000000664
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
print (dr.floor('S'))
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 03:25:42',
               '2011-01-01 06:51:25', '2011-01-01 10:17:08',
               '2011-01-01 13:42:51', '2011-01-01 17:08:34',
               '2011-01-01 20:34:17', '2011-01-02 00:00:00',
               '2011-01-02 03:25:42', '2011-01-02 06:51:25',
               '2011-01-02 10:17:08', '2011-01-02 13:42:51',
               '2011-01-02 17:08:34', '2011-01-02 20:34:17',
               '2011-01-03 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```